# Disable Power from Ethernet

Tags: ethernet, ifconfig

I'm trying to "turn off" the power that goes to a device over Ethernet. I'm using this card: https://www.startech.com/Networking-IO/Adapter-Cards/4-port-gigabit-poe-pcie-network-card~ST4000PEXPSE; it has the Realtek RTL8111E.

ifconfig (NAME) down does not actually shut off the power, it only disables the connection. Is this possible on Ubuntu?

Ubuntu 16.04

4.13.0-45-generic

Comment: Welcome to U&L :). I don't know, but it might depend on the specific version of the driver. It would be great if you could specify the version of Ubuntu you run your tests on - as a general rule.  For hardware-related things like this, it would also be nice if you could show the kernel version (result of `uname -r`).

Comment: You might see if `ethtool --show-features eth0` lists any POE things you can toggle. It is not a standard feature.

Comment: ok ive updated it

Answer (score 1):

After looking into this a bit more, it seems like there's no way to fully power down the card using anything from the kernel layer up. This is because of how pci works on the motherboard. On most boards, when they're turned on, the slot gets power rather you like it or not, unless you change some BIOS setting.

Having the ability to disable the cards individually from software would require some extra piece of hardware or something.

Comment: thanks for the asnwer! but that doesnt seem to work... I tried 
`root@sohit-System-Product-Name:~# echo 0 > /sys/bus/pci/slots/1-1/power
root@sohit-System-Product-Name:~# echo 0 > /sys/bus/pci/slots/1/power `
and the power is still going through my ethernet port. Those were both folders inside slots

Comment: @Sohit edited the answer, apparently this seems to be impossible on modern motherboards :( sorry